# stayed 86 days in netherlands, 180 days is up can i go back

Tags: schengen

went first time beginning of feb 2015, then again in march, up until aug 2015 for a total of 86 days, then went elsewhere.
question is it has been 180 days since first visit in feb.  so can i go back to netherlands now ?

Comment: What's your citizenship? For most people, it does not work that way anymore.

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule for an explanation of the rules and a link to a calculator.

Comment: im canadian....when i read it says after the 180 days it starts again and it goes back from the first visit which was Feb  ?

Comment: @mjk110: No, that's not what it says, except for a select few nationalities that don't include Canada. A new 180-day period starts EACH DAY no matter where in the world you are on that day, and you must be in compliance with the 90/180 rule for _all_ of the 180 different periods that include the day it is.

Comment: Since you are Canadian, [you can use the calculator mentioned in the first answer](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html) to find out yourself. You can probably go to the Netherlands now, but not for a full 90 days. The calculator will tell you exactly how long you may stay, based on the exact dates you were in the Schengen area.

Comment: when i did the schengen calculator it said i could stay another 31 days in netherlands for whatever reason, but how and where can i find out if this is true, im in canada, who do i contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schengen visa and the visa free visits like USA citizens get work on the bases that any day within  the Schengen zone you should be able to count back 180 days and should have fewer than 90 days within the zone.

So it is not about the first day you visited the Netherlands but how many days you stayed in March to August.
And whether you left the Schengen zone when you left the Netherlands, going to Belgium is not helpful, but going to Ireland is.

Comment: from mar to aug would have been 76 days, now in turkey

Comment: actually it is 48 days from march to august as you are saying, then went to turkey aug 25, still there but want to go back to netherlands,  on the calculator it says 31 more days to stay, how do you know if this is right, how do you find out?

Comment: Take a calendar and colour those days you have been within the Schengen zone, (any part of a day counts as a day within the zone,) and start counting days. Say you take the 15th of October as day to count back, you have to check all days you have been in the Schengen zone, back till mid April.

Comment: sorry i dont get the oct 15th and counting back part.  If you look at all my dates i entered,  why back till mid april  it was feb 7-16,  then mar 7-23, the June 27-Aug 25  the calander says i have 31 days still

Comment: If you do not believe that calculator, just stay the number of days you think you can stay, as long as it is shorter than what the calculator says. (Or do color that calendar and count back 180 days from the day you are, whenever and count the colored days within those 180 days.)